# How to require html files Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

Currently using:

- "webpack": "^2.4.1"
- "angular": "^1.6.3"

Current usage that gives the error that I need an appropriate loader:

```js
var root = {
  template: require('./root.html')
};
```

```js
{
  test: /\*.html$/,
  use: 'raw-loader!html-minifier-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

But if I do either of the followings it loads fine:

```js
var root = {
  templateUrl: './root.html'
};
```

```js
var root = {
  template: require('raw-loader!./root.html')
};
```

Do I have to specifically use the loader in-line if I want to require the HTML file? I thought that's what the loader in webpack config was for unless I'm not aware of this change for Webpack 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [test condition](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) is incorrect. It would only match if a file name *literally* contained a `*`, for example:

```
root*.html
root*ahtml
root*bhtml
```

You want

```
/\.html$/
```

instead. It's a regular expression, not a glob pattern.

Comment: I tired this, not it gives me two different errors. can't find the file(./root.html), and Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader!html-minifier-loader' in. any other suggestions? please and thanks!

Comment: I guess the `!` syntax [is not supported anymore](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-use). Try `use: ['raw-loader', 'html-minifier-loader']` instead. I would also try to only use `raw-loader` first.

Comment: boom! that was it. the regex, and the array syntax is what did it. thanks for the help!